# The "theory of compound partitions"

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, integer-partitions

I was reading a sort of mini-bio on [Sylvester](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Joseph_Sylvester) the other day and a "Theory of Compound Partitions" was mentioned in the discussion of his research interests. I wanted to ask, is this the same or the precursor to [Partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_partition) from Number Theory today? Thanks to all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that to get a compound partition of $n$, you take a partition of $n$ and then partition each of the parts in that partition. I gather this from the first paragraph of G. S. Ely, The Method of Graphs Applied to Compound Partitions, American Journal of Mathematics Vol. 6, No. 1, 1883 - 1884, Pages 382-384, which may or may not be freely available at http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.2307/2369233.

Comment: Ah, yes; that clears up a lot. Thanks!